# Downstream/Child Pipeline does not trigger with merge requests

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

> childpipeline.yml

```
stages:
  - test_stage
image:
  name: someimage:0.0.2
  entrypoint: ["sh", "-c"]

test:
  stage: test_stage
  script:
    - pwd
  rules:
   - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "parent_pipeline"
```

> Parentpipeline.yml

```
workflow:
  rules:
    # Avoid duplicate pipelines when pushing into an existing MR..
    #- if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS
      #when: never
    - when: always
stages:
 - stats

stats:
 stage: stats
 variables:
  PARENT_ID : $CI_PIPELINE_ID
 trigger:
    include:
      project: someproject
      ref: main
      file: pathtochild
 rules:
   - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
```

The child pipeline does not trigger and I see the following Error:
I tried chainging the rules and workflow but still the same. I'd appreciate if there is any insight on this
[image: Error]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the configuration of the *downstream project pipeline* (childpipeline.yml).

> rules:
> - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"

You are triggering the pipeline from the parent pipeline:

```yaml
 trigger:
    include:
      project: someproject
      ref: main
      file: pathtochild
```

Because the downstream child pipeline is NOT a merge request pipeline, and the only job in the downstream pipeline is configured to ONLY run when `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` is `merge_request_event` -- but when you trigger a downstream project, its `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` is independent from the parent's pipeline source.

See the docs: [Use rules to control downstream pipeline jobs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html#use-rules-to-control-downstream-pipeline-jobs) for more information. Specifically:

> When you trigger a downstream pipeline with the `trigger` keyword, the value of the `$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` predefined variable for all jobs is:
>
> - `pipeline` for multi-project pipelines.
> - `parent_pipeline` for parent-child pipelines.

So, to fix this, you should change the `rules:` in the downstream project to allow jobs to run when the `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` is `parent_pipeline`

Comment: First of all thanks!, I changed source to `parent_pipeline` but the problem still persists. Interestingly when I change the include to a local config it works.

Comment: @UmairShahid Try adding a simple debug job without any rules to the downstream pipeline. Also double check that the error you're getting is actually the **same**.

Comment: Did that, the error remains the same. :(

Answer (score 0):

In my side, @sytech's solution works. However, you can try another way:

<childpipeline.yml>

> ```
>   rules:
>     - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
> ```

Refer [Run child pipelines with merge request pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html#use-rules-to-control-downstream-pipeline-jobs):

> Instead, use if: `$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID` to set child pipeline jobs to
> run only when the parent pipeline is a merge request pipeline.

Comment: The weird thing is that it works when I do a local include and gives this error when i do an include: project

Comment: I made a repo to demonstrate how to reproduce this: 
https://gitlab.com/UmairShahid/test_CI_1/-/tree/main